# error while starting namenode and datanode

Tags: hadoop

```
pc83@pc83-ThinkCentre-M92p:~$ start-all.sh
This script is Deprecated. Instead use start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh
15/10/12 13:24:26 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Incorrect configuration: namenode address dfs.namenode.servicerpc-address or dfs.namenode.rpc-address is not configured.
Starting namenodes on []
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-pc83-namenode-pc83-ThinkCentre-M92p.out
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-pc83-datanode-pc83-ThinkCentre-M92p.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-pc83-secondarynamenode-pc83-ThinkCentre-M92p.out
0.0.0.0: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in authority at index 7: hdfs://localhost:9000 
0.0.0.0:    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:859)
0.0.0.0:    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getDefaultUri(FileSystem.java:177)
0.0.0.0:    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.getAddress(NameNode.java:412)
0.0.0.0:    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.getServiceAddress(NameNode.java:406)
0.0.0.0:    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.initialize(SecondaryNameNode.java:229)
0.0.0.0:    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.<init>(SecondaryNameNode.java:192)
0.0.0.0:    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.main(SecondaryNameNode.java:671)
0.0.0.0: Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in authority at index 7: hdfs://localhost:9000 
0.0.0.0:    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2829)
15/10/12 13:24:42 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
starting yarn daemons
starting resourcemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-pc83-resourcemanager-pc83-ThinkCentre-M92p.out
localhost: starting nodemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-pc83-nodemanager-pc83-ThinkCentre-M92p.out
pc83@pc83-ThinkCentre-M92p:~$
```

in the above code i wanna start haoop services like

`namenode,datanode,secondarynamenode,node manager`

the command throws and error saying

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in authority at index 7:
```

so to over come this problem what i have to do.

Comment: See if this SO link helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17456798/installing-hadoop-java-exception-about-illegal-characters-at-index-7 & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528827/illegal-character-in-authority-at-index-7-hdfs-localhost9000-with-hadoop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same error. I got this error because of the Hadoop configuration file named `core-site.xml`. It might be possible that your `core-site.xml` contains the code given below:

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:9000 </value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

The error occurred because of the space present between 9000 and `</value>`. 
To overcome, replace the `core-site.xml` with the following snippet:

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

You have to remove the space between `9000 </valve>`, that should look like `9000</value>`.